# Type 'AbstractControl | null' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any> | null | undefined'

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

my component.ts code is

```
forms = new FormGroup({
    topics: new FormArray([]),
  });

  addTopic(topic: HTMLInputElement) {
    (this.refForm as FormArray).push(new FormControl(topic.value));
    // topic.value = '';
  }

  get refForm() {
    return this.forms.get('topics');
  }
```

and .html file has following code.

```
<form [formGroup]="forms">
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    (keyup.enter)="addTopic(topic)"
    #topic
  />
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li *ngFor="let topic of forms.get('topics')">
      class="list-group-item">
      {{ topic.value }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

I tried to find and fix the problem but solutions or answer are not available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to iterate over controls but you're passing an instance of `AbstractControl` or possible `null` value to `ngFor` loop.

I guess you wanted to pass array of controls in your `FormArray`.

You already have a get helper that can be enhanced with correct type:

```
get refForm() {
  return this.forms.get('topics') as FormArray;
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

with the above code you can correct your html

```
*ngFor="let topic of refForm.controls"
```

Comment: this code got this error Type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<AbstractControl> | null | undefined'.

Comment: Please look carefully at all code I added. Did you add `as FormArray`?

Comment: yes did.  get refForm() {
    return this.forms.get('topics') as FormArray;
  }

Comment: Please test my code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vgzuke?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: it works here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vgzuke?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: but I don't know what is the error in my code. id doesn't work. and thank you for answering me.

Comment: Whats your Angular version?

Comment: sure you iterate ove refFom. **controls** ?

Comment: thank you so much @yurzui for your time. It work my mistake is I iterate over 'forms' object but in your code  iterate over 'refForm.controls' its works thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line:

```
<li *ngFor="let topic of forms.get('topics')">
```

with:

```
<li *ngFor="let topic of forms.get('topics')?.value">
```

That should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this by changing `form.get` to `[control]="this.form.controls['reply']"`